# BASH mkntfs со своим UUID

Tags: linux, bash, ntfs

При форматировании раздела этой командой, `UUID` раздела сохраняется и `/etc/fstab` не приходится исправлять лишний раз.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L "/label" -U "$(sudo blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sda1)" /dev/sda1
```

Вопрос в том, есть ли что - то подобное для формата `.ntfs` ?

Пробовал `mkntfs`, `mkfs.ntfs` но они не понимают команду которую перечислил выше, вроде бы в мануале написано -U опция у mkntfs присутствует, но не разобрался полностью как реализовать, а просто для проверки неправильно форматировать раздел не хочется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«нативных» средств, увы, нет.

но *uuid* довольно несложно поменять и «руками».

согласно [информации с сайта ntfs.com](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-partition-boot-sector.htm), *uuid* (aka *volume serial number*) записан в нулевом секторе раздела со смещением `0x48` от его начала, занимает восемь байт, и байты расположены в «обратном» порядке (сначала последний, потом предпоследний и т.д.).

проверим.

1. создадим пустой файл размером 100 мегабайт:

   ```
   $ truncate -s 100M /tmp/img
   ```
2. подключим его как loop-устройство (иначе *mkntfs* отказывается создавать в нём файловую систему). опция `--show` позволяет сразу увидеть, под каким именем файл подключился:

   ```
   $ sudo losetup --show -f /tmp/img
   /dev/loop0
   ```

   если опцию `--show` забыли, то можно посмотреть отдельно:

   ```
   $ sudo losetup -l -a
   NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
   /dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /tmp/img
   ```
3. создадим теперь файловую систему:

   ```
   $ sudo mkntfs /dev/loop0
   ...
   ```
4. и посмотрим, какой *uuid* у неё:

   ```
   $ sudo blkid | grep loop
   /dev/loop0: UUID="6E596895539DB263" TYPE="ntfs"
   ```

   весьма похоже на восемь байт.
5. теперь сверим с содержимым файла с образом:

   ```
   $ hd /tmp/img | head -n 5 | tail -n 1
   00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  63 b2 9d 53 95 68 59 6e  |........c..S.hYn|
   ```

   так и есть! восемь байт в «обратной» последовательности, начиная со смещения `0x48`.
6. не забываем отключить loop-устройство:

   ```
   $ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
   ```

---

осталось только переписать эти восемь байт своими данными (`72` — это `0x48` в десятичной системе счисления):

```
$ echo -ne '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07' | dd of=/tmp/img seek=72 bs=1 conv=notrunc
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
8 bytes copied, 0.00015337 s, 52.2 kB/s
```

проверяем:

```
$ sudo losetup --show -f /tmp/img
/dev/loop0
$ sudo blkid | grep loop
/dev/loop0: UUID="0706050403020100" TYPE="ntfs"
```

всё верно!

не забываем отключить loop-устройство:

```
$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

---

для изменения байтов в реальном разделе, естестенно, программу *dd* надо будет запускать с полномочиями супер-пользователя (например, с помощью *sudo*), и указать в параметре `of=` не файл `/tmp/img`, а нужный раздел, где у вас находится файловая система (что-то вроде `/dev/sdb1` и т.п.).

возможно, чтобы новое значение отобразилось в выводе программы *blkid*, потребуется сообщить программе *linux*, чтобы она перечитала информацию о разделах устройства (что-то вроде `sudo partx /dev/sdb`).

---

да, чтобы вручную не переписывать байты в обратном порядке, дополняя их символами `\x`, можно воспользоваться такой примерно конструкцией:

```
$ echo 0001020304050607 | sed 's/../\\x&\n/g' | tac | tr -d '\n'
\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\x00
```

и подставить её сразу в вышеупомянутую команду:

```
$ echo -ne "$(echo 0001020304050607 | sed 's/../\\x&\n/g' | tac | tr -d '\n')" | dd ...
```

Comment: @S1lllver, понятно, что исправить строчку в файле `/etc/fstab` — значительно проще, чем манипулировать набором байт непосредственно на блочном устройстве, но ведь вопрос-то как раз и был об «альтернативе» исправлению строчки в `/etc/fstab`. да, ответ получился, пожалуй, слишком длинным: можно было ограничиться и одной строчкой с командой. но захотелось «разжевать»…

Comment: `sed  's/.../.../g'` -> `grep -o ..`

Comment: Да, ответ и правда является альтернативой , спасибо за подробный ответ в любом случае )